# Python NameNode script

Tags: python, hadoop

Hi I need to write a python script to be able to monitor a particular process on linux. To be more specific i want to be able to monitor whether or not Namenode Process is running or not, and i want to be able to get a message of some sort, if the process goes down. I saw something like this on the forum, is this something i should be writing and why do i get this error?

```
>>> if 'namenode' not in          subprocess.Popen('tasklist',stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(                                   [0]:
    ... subprocess.Popen('namenode')
    File "<stdin>", line 2
    subprocess.Popen('namenode')
             ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/).  You could monitor a process like this.

```
import psutil 

proc = None

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name == 'namenode':
        proc = p
        break

if proc is None:
    print("Can't find namenode")
else:
    proc.wait()

print('Namenode not running')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try this out and let you know how it went. Thanks again CJ.